# How to print results of cat(sprintf()) without quotes in R?

Tags: r

I have a variable `today <- Sys.Date()` , which I would like to use in a file output using cat:

```
cat(sprintf("title: NYC Weekly \"%s\"\n", today))
```

The problem is that this outputs the date in quotes, like this:

```
title: NYC Weekly "2015-02-09"
```

My desired output is

```
title: NYC Weekly 2015-02-09
```

Is there a way to print without the quotes??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
cat(sprintf('title: NYC Weekly %s\n', today))
#title: NYC Weekly 2015-02-09
```

Comment: That worked. I'll mark it as correct asap. cat(sprintf('Thanks a million!'))